# Create a CALayer on each click of a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation, calayer

I got an IBAction and a CALayer (in the viewDidLoad) so what I need is to add a CALayer (in diffrent CGPoints) when the user click the add button.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What? You say "I have an idea for a program and I'm hoping the internet will write it for me?" Show some effort, man! What have you tried? Have you looked up code to add a layer to a view? Have you tried to make that code work with your app? IF you had problems, post your code and explain where you're stuck, and then we will help you.

Comment: I already did all of this but finally the problem was the positioning only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a newbie in iOS, that's why I'm answering the answer, else I'll suggest to use google.

You can do it like:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    static float xPos = 0;
    static float yPos = 0;

    CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [myLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f)];
    [myLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)];   //You need to change the value here dynamically for changing the layer position
    [myLayer setFontSize:20];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:myLayer];

    xPos += 50;
    yPos += 50;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, but that's not showing a new layer on each click on the button

Comment: @KevinMartin: did you changed the points, I mentioned in the comment ? I think no, then the layers are added to the same position.

Comment: So how I'll change the points (Sorry I'm new in iOS development)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your IBAction, simply use this code:

```
// Create a new CALayer
CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer];

// Modify frame
myLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

// Modify position (change for your necessity)
myLayer.position = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f); 

// Add layer to the actual view's layer
[self.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```